# Remove duplicates from =index with multiple matches in excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

Column A has a list of names which I Created a named range "names'
Column B has a list of ips which i created a named range "ips"
I have a formula that appends to column c all the ip's that are parallel to the name. How can I remove the duplicates? Is there a way to do this is the formula I already have?

```
{=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(name=A2,ips,""))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having access to Dynamic Array formulas:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(ips,name=a2)))
```

---

If per chance one has TEXTJOIN but not the Dynamic Array formulas use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF((name=A2)*(ROW(ips)=IFERROR(MATCH(ips,IF(name=A2,ips),0),9999)),ips,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: I am getting #NAME with this formula

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: O365 16.0 64Bit

Comment: Then try to update it.  The dynamic formulas are being rolled out.  Should be out to everyone now.

Comment: @ScottCraner just solved problem with "TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(ips,name=a2)))", editing to suit. Perfect.